# How to Show Popup When Click on URL From Simple HTML Page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I Have created 1 Simple Admin Panel.
In Navigation Menu, We have Change Password Menu.
In Which I have changepassword.php linked.
I want to open changepassword.php file in popup, not in same or new window.
Can anyone guide me how can i do.
Pleas check attached Image for referance.
Thanks

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5LH8.png)

Comment: That's not really a "popup" in webdev terms. That's a "modal dialog". If you Google that you'll find thousands of tutorials and hundreds of useful libraries to do it.

Comment: oh.. I was don't know it.. Thanks..

Comment: You're welcome. No harm in not knowing! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like [`jQuery UI`](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) dialogs or [`Bootstrap Modals`](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Just sloppily copy-pasted examples from a google search, but basic idea there.

in php, this may also work:

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

         <!-- // INCLUDE CHANGE PASSWORD -->
         <?php include("changepassword.php"); ?>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

but at that point you could format the changepassword.php to include the modal markup, and just include that as a "component".